# What is best way to compact styrofoam and discard it?

Tags: recycling

Every time I install appliances or get something which is breakable, it's covered in styrofoam. Now what is the best/cleanest way to compact and get rid of styrofoam?

I've known people who just put it in a container with acetone where it just dissolves, but I highly doubt it's eco-friendly and I'm not sure what to do with the solved substance afterwards (don't think pouring it down the drain is a smart idea).

What is best way to compact styrofoam and discard it?

Comment: Double check that it's not recyclable in your area. In my area there are places that will take it for free, which I didn't know about until recently.

Comment: +1 for recycling. It's rarely eligible for curbside pickup due to its bulk and tendency to develop a static charge and stick to everything in sight, but polystyrene actually recycles very well and there are companies which collect it for the purpose. Finding one, and delivering the stuff to them, can be a nuisance but that's definitely the "best" way to dispose of it. Easiest is to just shove it in a trash bag and put it out with the other garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume from your question that you live in a place where it's not recyclable.

Here's an idea: turn it into a resource and use it to improve your house's insulation! I am currently re-using strips of styrofoam packaging material to insulate around my new windows. You could put the bigger sheets of it on your attic floor and then cover it up with cellulose. Etc.

You could offer it up free on Craigslist too. You'd be surprised what people can do with what you might consider a waste product.

Comment: I'd be a bit careful about using it for house insulation -- styrofoam probably doesn't meet fire-safety codes.

Comment: It's going to be covered by a code-approved ignition barrier. The building material version--EPS insulation--is ridiculously flammable, so it's not like styforoam (the same material, after all) is much worse.